# Complete the sample data installation error

Tags: magento2

I was following the steps shown [Here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-clone.html#instgde-prereq-compose-clone-perms) to add sample data to my magento site for testing then i got this error stack below:

It was the last part of the installation where i executed this command: `php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:upgrade`

```
 Installing data... PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getDataByKey() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\magento2-sample-data\app\code\Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order\Converter.php:191
    Stack trace:
    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\magento2-sample-data\app\code\Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order\Converter.php(171): Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order\Converter->getProductAttributes(Array)
    #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\magento2-sample-data\app\code\Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order\Converter.php(76): Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order\Converter->convertProductData(Array)
    #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\magento2-sample-data\app\code\Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order.php(101): Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order\Converter->convertRow(Array)
    #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\magento2-sample-data\app\code\Magento\SalesSampleData\Setup\Installer.php(30): Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order->install(Array)
    #4 [internal function]: Magento\SalesSampleData\Setup\Installer->install()
    #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\State in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\magento2-sample-data\app\code\Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order\Converter.php on line 191

    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getDataByKey() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\magento2-sample-data\app\code\Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order\Converter.php:191
    Stack trace:
    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\magento2-sample-data\app\code\Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order\Converter.php(171): Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order\Converter->getProductAttributes(Array)
    #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\magento2-sample-data\app\code\Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order\Converter.php(76): Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order\Converter->convertProductData(Array)
    #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\magento2-sample-data\app\code\Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order.php(101): Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order\Converter->convertRow(Array)
    #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\magento2-sample-data\app\code\Magento\SalesSampleData\Setup\Installer.php(30): Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order->install(Array)
    #4 [internal function]: Magento\SalesSampleData\Setup\Installer->install()
    #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\State in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\magento2-sample-data\app\code\Magento\SalesSampleData\Model\Order\Converter.php on line 191
```

Comment: You installed Magento 2 via composer or a different way?

Comment: via composer, correct

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while running Linux virtual box on Windows.
Sample-data csv files had CRLF endings, so they were incorrectly processed.
I installed sample data via Git. Following commands helped me:

```
cd <path_to_sample_data>

git config core.autocrlf false

git reset --hard HEAD
```

Alternatevily you can run

```
cd <path_to_magento2>/vendor/magento

find ./ -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

This problem was also discussed there

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2400